# Microsoft Fakes unit testing with Windows Forms application(EXE)

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, microsoft-fakes

Microsoft Fakes library can replace calls to assemblies which we can not modify, [please refer docs](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh549175(v=vs.110).aspx). 
I want to unit test my Windows Forms application.

*Can we use Microsoft Fakes library to stub/shim calls from my EXE?*

Comment: You don't normally want to unit test methods in an EXE; but you can.  Your unit test project can reference the EXE.  I'd recommend you try to move things out into a class library and test the class library either directly or with Fakes.

Comment: *@Peter Ritchie*, thanks for reply. I researched how to fake EXE(Classes and its methods from EXE), but did not found tutorial/docs. If you have any tutorials/docs can you please share?